# DynamoDB query filtered by date less than a given one

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-dynamodb

I'm doing a java springboot project with DynamoDB. I have this problem:

I have a dynamoDB table that is constructed like this:

```
aws dynamodb create-table  \
    --table-name my-table \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=my_id,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=my_type,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=creation_date,AttributeType=N \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=my_id,KeyType=HASH \
        AttributeName=my_type,KeyType=RANGE \
    --billing-mode PAY_PER_REQUEST \
    --endpoint-url $ENDPOINT:$PORT \
    --global-secondary-indexes \
        "[
            {
                \"IndexName\": \"CreationDateIndex\",
                \"KeySchema\": [{\"AttributeName\":\"creation_date\",\"KeyType\":\"HASH\"}],
                \"Projection\":{
                    \"ProjectionType\":\"ALL\"
                },
                \"ProvisionedThroughput\": {
                    \"ReadCapacityUnits\": 10,
                    \"WriteCapacityUnits\": 5
                }
            }
        ]"
```

This is the Entity:

```
    @NotNull
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "my_id")
    protected UUID myId;

    @NotNull
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "my_type")
    protected String myType;

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "CreationDateIndex")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "creation_date")
    protected long creationDate;
```

I want to create a method in the repository that deletes all rows with creation_date less than the given date (actually I saved the epochSeconds as creation_date), but if I build the query I don't have the comparison option to add `.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LE)`.

How can I create a query?

The only solution I've found is to use DynamoDBScanExpression but that's not efficient. This is the current solution:

```
    @Override
    public boolean delete(long creationDateBefore) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("STARTING DELETING objects");
        List<MyEntity> objectsToDelete = findByCreationDateBefore(creationDateBefore);
        System.out.println("DELETING " + objectsToDelete.size() + " objects");
        return batchDelete(objectsToDelete).isEmpty();
    }

    private List<MyEntity> findByCreationDateBefore(long creationDateBefore) {
        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
        scanExpression.addFilterCondition(
                "creation_date",
                new Condition()
                        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LE)
                        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(String.valueOf(creationDateBefore)))
        );

        return dbMapper.scan(MyEntity.class, scanExpression);
    }
```

Do you have other possible solutions?
I could modify the table but the index must always be Hash my_id + Range my_type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You index currently only has `creation_date` which only allows you to specify an exact date, as you must always know the entire partition key when Querying.

To overcome this you can add a static value to your items, lets call it `GSI1_PK`:

| GSI_PK | creation_date | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-16T00:00:000 | some data |
| 1 | 2023-12-16T01:00:000 | some data |
| 1 | 2023-12-16T02:00:000 | some data |
| 1 | 2023-12-16T03:00:000 | some data |
| 1 | 2023-12-16T03:00:000 | some data |
| 1 | 2023-12-16T04:00:000 | some data |

Now you can issue a `Query` where `GSI_PK = 1 AND creation_date < $DATE`